# Numerical integration of a function with a singularity

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, improper-integrals, numerical-calculus

I'm trying to compute numerically a function like the following:
$$
F(t)=\int_{0}^{t}{\frac{f(\tau)}{\sqrt{t-\tau}}d\tau}
$$
I tried to adopt the composite Simpson's rule, but the problem is that when $\tau=t$, I have a division by $0$, so I can't evaluate the integrand at the last point. I have also tried some substitutions but without success. Could someone please help me with how can I proceed to get rid of it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does your $f(\tau)$ function look like?  Is it a straightforward polynomial (or can it be reasonably be approximated by one)?

Comment: It might be helpful to write this as $\sqrt{t}\int_0^1\frac{f(t\tau)-f(t)}{\sqrt{1-\tau}}\,\mathrm{d}\tau+2\sqrt{t}f(t)$

Comment: It's given by $f(\tau) = 1-\tanh(A\tau^{-7/4})/(A\tau^{-7/4})$, where $A$ is a constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider the change of variable $t-\tau = y^2$ the integral becomes
$$
\int_{\sqrt t}^0 \frac{f(t-y^2)}{y}\cdot (-2y) dy = 2 \int_0^{\sqrt{t}} f(t-y^2) dy.
$$

Assuming that the singularity was expressed in the term $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t-\tau}}$ and $f$ is nice enough, Simpson's method will now work in standard way.